# SED Remove All HTML Tags Except Links

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to remove all html tags but leave
E.G.  `<a href="http://www.domain.com/">Link Title</a>`

So far this works for me except that it removes the `</a>` part.

```
sed -e 's/<[^">]*>//g'
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Links are not the only tags with attributes.

Comment: Yes I know, but this is what I needed ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you've written removes any blocks of `<Stuff>` where `Stuff` doesn't have any double quotes in it. If for example there were a perfectly valid bit of html like:

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/'>Link Title</a>
```

or even some odd html like:

```
<a href=http://www.domain.com/>Link Title</a>
```

it wouldn't work for you.

Regular expressions are considered a notoriously bad way to process HTML except in cases where you know exactly the full range of variations you can possibly process.

So read [this viewpoint](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) first.

I could suggest something like:

```
sed -e 's/<[^a>/!][^ >][^>]*>//g;s/<\/[^a>][^>]*>//g'
```

Comment: Perfect SED Rule thank you dlamblin. This effectively removes all of html tags and leaves links alone.

Comment: @Tux You're welcome. If you run this on any HTML that contains `<abbr>` `<acronym>` `<address>` `<applet>` or `<area>` and you break it... you buy it. :)

Comment: LOL That the point, I did not want any tags with or without attributes but only simple tags. It just what I wanted. Thank you =)

Comment: I just remembered that comment styled tags could break this... like `<!-- some <b>stuff</b> I commented out -->`